# Why doesn't Qemu boot my custom linux kernel?

Tags: linux, qemu

I was watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awik6Iittu4 on building our custom linux os.
The problem is that when I do `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda image` I get this output

[image]

And then it instantly reboots, in loop. What am I doing wrong? Is the tutorial old?
Note that I didn't modify even one line of the kernel, I only did what the tutorial did.

I did this stuff on an Ubuntu x64 machine in VMware, and my main machine is Windows 10.
What i did:

```
1 - sudo apt install build-essential musl-tools grub-pc-bin
2 - git clone https://github.com/MichielDerhaeg/build-linux
3 - cd build-linux/    (where the git cloned)
4 - git submodule init && git submodule update
5 - make -j4 image
6 - i said the command above
```

Comment: Check how to debug whatever is running under Qemu, that should help pinpoint where it fails.

Comment: maybe the boot argument should set earlyprintk and stdout-path? you can pass it the the --append option when calling qemu.